# Getting aborted error for Ext-js-4 Ajax request synchrnous call

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to get a solution for 'aborted' error while invoking a service call from Ext-js-4.
I made async attirbute as 'false', as per my understanding this will make the request as a synchronous one. Following is my store code , it has Proxy definition.

```
Ext.define('RD.store.Rules', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
       requires: 'RD.model.Rules',
       model: 'RD.model.Rules',

       proxy: {
              type: 'ajax',
              async : false,
              url: '/admin/client/test/list.in',
              actionMethods: {
                     create: 'POST',
                     read: 'GET',
                     update: 'POST',
                     destroy: 'POST'
              },
              reader: {
                     type: 'json',
                     root: 'rules'
              }
       },

       autoLoad: false,
       autoSync: false,

       // Event listeners
       listeners: {
              'beforeload': function(self, operation) {
                     console.log('RD.store.Rules beforeload');
                     console.log(self, operation);

                     self.total = null;
                     self.returned = null;
              },
              'load': function(self, records, successful) {
                     console.log('RD.store.Rules load');
                     console.log(self, records, successful);

                     var data = self.getProxy().getReader().rawData;
                     self.total = data.total;
                     self.returned = data.returned;
              }
       }
});
```

If i invoke a request by using this proxy , i will get an 'aborted' error after 27 seconds.
For testing purpose i added timeout attribute to proxy as follows

```
       proxy: {
              type: 'ajax',
              async : false,
              **timeout: 300000,** 
              url: '/admin/client/test/list.in',
```

after this change i'm able to get result after 40 to 50 sec.

can we avoid this error without using timeout attribute ? It's not necessary to give timeout attribute for a synchronous request ?

Please share your valuable comments on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

50 sec.?? You'll have to deliver game boys with your soft ;p

Anyway, what's your problem with setting the `timeout` to an upper value? If your request takes that long, you've got no choice but to wait for it...

Synchronous or async will not change anything for the response time or the timeout. But in general, and in this case especially, it is an extremely bad idea to make the request synchronous, since it will freeze your entire app for all that long...

Comment: Hi Rixo, Thx for u'r comments. i fixed it by setting timeout with a higher value.